# Importing AWS information from CloudFormation to CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild, aws-cloudformation

I have a pipeline in AWS with Codestar, CodeBuild, CloudFormation, etc.

I am trying to figure out how to get information from the CloudFormation step returned to the CodeBuild step.  Let me break it down:

1. I have a `buildspec.yml` for CodeBuild

   ```
   # buildspec.yml

   ...
   phases:
    ...
    build:
      commands:
        - aws cloudformation package --region $REGION --template template.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template $OUTPUT_TEMPLATE
   ```
2. The above kicks off a CloudFormation build using our `template.yml`

   ```
   # template.yml

    ...
    S3BucketAssets:
       Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    ...
   ```
3. At this point, it creates a unique name for an S3 bucket.  Awesome.  Now, for step 2 in my `buildspec.yml` for CodeBuild, I want to push items to the S3 bucket just created in the CloudFormation template.  BUT, I don't know how to get the dynamically created name of the S3 bucket from the CloudFormation template.  I want something similar to:

   ```
   # buildspec.yml

   ...
   phases:
    ...
    build:
      commands:
        # this is the same step as shown above
        - aws cloudformation package --region $REGION --template template.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template $OUTPUT_TEMPLATE
        # this is the new step
        - aws s3 sync dist_files/ s3://{NAME_OF_THE_NEW_S3_BUCKET}
   ```

How can I accomplish getting the dynamically named S3 bucket so that I can push to it?

I am aware that within a CloudFormation template, you can reference the S3 bucket name with something like `!GetAtt [ClientWebAssets, WebsiteURL]`.  But, I do not know how to get that information out of the cloudformation template and back into the codebuild template.

Answer (score 0):

You could move to using CodePipeline. Stage one would be deploying the application via cloudformation with an output artifact being the stack creation output

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html#action-requirements